# How to know when the consumer stop consuming

Tags: go, rabbitmq

I wanted to create a client that pings to notify the server that it is still online, and when the client stops pinging, the server notifies that there is a problem with the client by sending a message to the terminal.

code for illustrate :

**Server** :

```
import (
    "log"

    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
)

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    defer ch.Close()

    err = ch.ExchangeDeclare(
        "logs",   // name
        "fanout", // type
        true,     // durable
        false,    // auto-deleted
        false,    // internal
        false,    // no-wait
        nil,      // arguments
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare an exchange")

    q, err := ch.QueueDeclare(
        "",    // name
        false, // durable
        false, // delete when unused
        true,  // exclusive
        false, // no-wait
        nil,   // arguments
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare a queue")

    err = ch.QueueBind(
        q.Name, // queue name
        "",     // routing key
        "logs", // exchange
        false,
        nil,
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to bind a queue")

    msgs, err := ch.Consume(
        q.Name, // queue
        "",     // consumer
        true,   // auto-ack
        false,  // exclusive
        false,  // no-local
        false,  // no-wait
        nil,    // args
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to register a consumer")

    forever := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        for d := range msgs {

            log.Printf(" [x] %s", d.Body)

        }
    }()

    log.Printf(" [*] Waiting for logs. To exit press CTRL+C")

    <-forever
}
```

**Client** :

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/streadway/amqp"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func failOnError(err error, msg string) {
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("%s: %s", msg, err)
    }
}

func main() {
    conn, err := amqp.Dial("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/")
    failOnError(err, "Failed to connect to RabbitMQ")
    defer conn.Close()

    ch, err := conn.Channel()
    failOnError(err, "Failed to open a channel")
    defer ch.Close()

    err = ch.ExchangeDeclare(
        "logs",   // name
        "fanout", // type
        true,     // durable
        false,    // auto-deleted
        false,    // internal
        false,    // no-wait
        nil,      // arguments
    )
    failOnError(err, "Failed to declare an exchange")

    body := "ping"

    for i := 0; i < 4; i++ {
        err = ch.Publish(

            "logs", // exchange
            "",     // routing key
            false,  // mandatory
            false,  // immediate
            amqp.Publishing{
                ContentType: "text/plain",
                Body:        []byte(body),
            })
        time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)
        failOnError(err, "Failed to publish a message")

        log.Printf(" [x] %s sent to the server", body)
    }

}
```

I was wondering, how can we know when the consumer stop consuming. Maybe with this information i will be able to know when the client is dead ?

Comment: publishers and consumers are independent entities and know nothing of each other; that's the point of having a message broker

Comment: To know when the consumer stop consuming, you can search "healthcheck microservices" on google

Comment: Based on your client code, the possible reason for client failure would be connection errors...
Why you do not run the terminal command inside of the client itself? instead of `failOnError()`

Comment: @AminShojaei Because i am a newbie and dont know how to do it

Comment: another way would be sending im-healthy messages by client every(let's say 10 secs) and listening by the server. If the server didn't receive a message after 30 seconds, it means the client is probably dead, stopped or stuck

Comment: @AminShojaei that's what i was trying to do at first, as you can see with my "for" loop in my client code but after the time the client stop sending I dont know how to check with my server if there is a message or no, do you have an i idea how to do so ?

Comment: I strongly recommend dropping the idea and changing the client code, and preventing it from panicking in case of error. For example, you can put the RabbitMQ connection initiation into a for loop and let it retry forever to establish the connection. If the client goes down, you can restart it using Docker and Docker-compose, etc.